# Multiple methods named 'location' found with mismatched result, parameter type, or attributes

Tags: ios, calendar-store

I have read the other questions concerning multiple methods but still do not know how to fix my code.   I would be grateful for help with this.    I have put a *** around the statement where the error occurs.

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: 
      (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"eventCell";
    EQCalendarCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
       cell = [[EQCalendarCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.titleLabel.text = [[self.eventsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] title];
```

---

```
    cell.locationLabel.text = [[self.eventsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] location];
```

---

```
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat: @"dd-MM-yy HH:mm"];
    NSString *startDateString = [df stringFromDate:[[self.eventsList
    objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] startDate]];

    cell.startDateLabel.text = startDateString;

    NSString *endDateString = [df stringFromDate:[[self.eventsList
    objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] endDate]];


    cell.endDateLabel.text = endDateString;

    return cell;
    }
```

Thanking you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Casting the result of retrieving the object from the `self.eventsList` collection should solve the problem. E.g.:

`cell.locationLabel.text = [((MyClassName *)[self.eventsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]) location];`

Replacing `MyClassName` with the name of the class in the collection.

Answer (score 3):

You need to cast `[self.eventsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` to the relevant type so that the compiler knows what data type your are dealing with.

Without seeing how your self.eventList list is populated it's not possible to tell you the solution exactly, but your line should be replaced with something like this (split into two lines for clarity, but you could use a cast instead of a variable to keep it on one line)

```
MyEventClass *event = [self.eventsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.locationLabel.text = [event location];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast EKEvent class. This will solve your problem...

```
EKEvent *event = [self.eventlist objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *placeStr=[event location];
```

Answer (score 0):

In one scenario, if the factory method that creates the object has return type "id" then the compiler will check the method signature in all the classes. If compiler find the same method signature in more than one class then it will raise the issue. So replace the return type "id" with "specific class name".